# Nesting Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Train DB in SQL Server. I have source and destination column and I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server to find the shortest path, travel time, waiting time and total distance.

What I want now is to generate the result set for single source to all destination and store it in a table.

For example: I have 5 source and 5 destinations then I need total 25 result rows

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Don't you think you should include the current solution you have?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be thinking "loops" at all in SQL. It's a set-based language and tends to produce the best results when you ask it to work with sets, not individual rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the table that will hold the 25 row resultset your procedure can just insert the rows as the calculation is run. If you want help with the procedure edit, consider posting your stored proc. If you have a table for the results, post its script too.

Without your code the answer has to be more generic.

Comment: If I were you, I'd focus on answering clear and straightforward questions (which this one isn't) with clear and straightforward answers (which this one isn't), until I gained some rep.

Comment: you're right. I wanted to just comment but couldn't. he should've posted his sp and table(s). thanks